# Quasar Firestore field equality query filter doesn't work

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, quasar-framework

I am using quasar to read/write unique data to Cloud Firestore but the following code doesn't work. It fails to detect existing record based on the `title` field. I am using the Web Version 9 syntax.

```
<script>
import seedData from "../../data/todos.json";
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  query,
  where,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore();
seedData.forEach(async (todo) => {
    console.log("Processing ", todo.title, "...");
    const q = query(
        collection(db, "todos"),
        where("title", "==", todo.title)
    );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log("Add missing todo: ", todo.title);
        await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), { todo });
        this.todos.push(todo);
    } else {
        console.log("Skip existing record: ", querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
    }
});
</script>
```

Sample data:

```
[{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Learn Quasar", 
    "completed": false
 },
 {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Learn Vue", 
    "completed": false
 },
 {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Learn Firebase", 
    "completed": false
 }
]
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Duplicate data seen at the browser in `quasar dev` debug session:
[image]

Duplicate data seen at the Firestore console:
[image: Cloud Firestore console]

Repo: https://github.com/khteh/quasar

Comment: Thanks for that. Now what is the output that you get when you run this code on this data? And can you show the database document(s) for which you expect a different result?

Comment: Duplicate data as seen at the browser and Firestore console!

Comment: None of the `console.log` statements from your code are showing in the output you shared. Are you sure the duplicates come from this code (which looks correct at first glance)?

Comment: Updated code snippet and browser screen capture. It's obvious that the query is not effective to detect duplicates. Bug!?!

Comment: Chances of there being a bug in a single-field equality filter in the database, that nobody has found in the years that the product has been out seem small. It's always possible of course, but I'd sooner expect something in the application to be wrong. I tried reproducing the problem without success, and posted my efforts below (because they're too long for a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to include the full path to the field used for filter `<object>.<field>`. In this case, it is `todo.title`. So, `where("todo.title", "==", todo.title)` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce the problem with this simplified code:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "69534155"),
  where("title", "==", "Learn Quasar")
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
if (querySnapshot.empty) {
  console.log("Add missing todo: ", "Learn Quasar");
} else {
  console.log("Skip existing record: ", querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
}
```

*For the full working code, see: https://jsbin.com/gekuqec/3/edit?html,console*

This prints:

> Skip existing record: ...

While when I change the title to something non-existing it prints:

> Add missing todo:

I recommend stepping through the code in a debugger, and checking whether `todo.title` really has the value that exists in your documents.

If you still have the problem after this, try reproducing it in a similar minimal setup as I've shared here, so that we can have a look at that.

Comment: Found the culprit. It's the object structure used in the query syntax that's wrong. `title` is one level down below `todo` object. So, `where("todo.title", "==", todo.title)` fixes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that in the screenshot. Good catch! You might want to post a self-answer for it, in case somebody has the same problem in the future.